# Refering to a column name in a formula with a string variable in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to reference the name of a column in a formula by using a variable `target`, which consists of pasted strings.

```
target = paste0("C","_inf")
model.matrix(target~., model.df)
```

This results in the error

```
Error in model.frame.default(object, data, xlev = xlev) :
  variable lengths differ
```

However, referencing the name of the column directly as in `model.matrix(C_inf~., model.df)` results in no such error and a perfectly fine model matrix.
I guess this is caused by the type of `target` being `chr`, but I can't seem to figure out how to specify to use it as placeholder for a column name. Could someone tell me where I'm going wrong and how to approach fixing it?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

We can create the formula in `paste` or `reformulate`

```
model.matrix(reformulate(".", response = target), model.df)
```

Or with `paste`

```
model.matrix(as.formula(paste0(target, "~.")), model.df)
```

---

or can use `glue`

```
model.matrix(glue::glue("{target}~ ."), model.df)
```

Comment: Perfect, that works. Thanks a lot! So `target` being a string can't be solved by any kind of "transformation" (such as `as.formula`) on its own? We always need to retransform the whole formula if I want to use a string variable in it?

Comment: if it is a formula, then you can use `update` as well.